# Read until empty line and save as new file - python

Tags: python, email, jupyter-notebook, txt

first of all, completely new to python, so this question might be easy.

I want to read a text file and save it as a new file, separate the header in emails from the body. The place where the header ends is the empty line under "X-UID: 81" (as seen in the image). Not all emails have the "X-UID:" so the empty line is the place where I want to separate it. Is there an easy way to do this?

My code currently looks like this:

```
with open("1.txt") as fReader:
 corpus = fReader.read()

loc = corpus.find("X-UID")
print(corpus[:loc])
```

- This sort of works, but I can't separate at the empty line. And don't know how to save as new file

[Example email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtsDx.png)

Comment: Search for `'\n\n'`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to do this is to read the entire file as one string, and split it by `X-UID: 81` (provided that this substring is present, of course), like so:

```py
parts = s.split('X-UID: 81')
header, body = parts[0], parts[1]
```

If the file doesn't contain `X-UID: 81`, you could just `split()` by double newline (`\n\n`) with `maxsplit=1` to make sure it doesn't split further on the newlines in the email body:

```py
parts = s.split('\n\n', maxsplit=1)
header, body = parts[0], parts[1]
```